# Parsing Facebook Json results

Tags: json, facebook, r

I'm trying to use the following code to parse a response from the Facebook API, and I get a strange error... below is the code and error... Any thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Link to code: [How to get most popular Facebook post in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046111/how-to-get-most-popular-facebook-post-in-r)

The error I get is:

```
Error in myposts[[1]]$paging$"next" : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Here is what the data looks like:

```
tail(myposts[[1]])
```

results in:

```
$paging

previous 
"https://graph.facebook.com/74133697733/posts?access_token=###token###&limit=25&since=1361736602&__previous=1" 

next

"https://graph.facebook.com/74133697733/posts?access_token=###token###&limit=25&until=1359727199"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `paging` element is a named vector, not a list, so you can't use `$` to get sub-elements.

The following should work :

```
myposts[[1]]$paging["next"]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that helps but it it looks like the while loop is still not recognizing the "next.path" text and using it to retrieve the next page of Json results...

Comment: Maybe, but that's another question.

Comment: Thanks, I've marked this question answered and here is the follow-on question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072142/parsing-facebook-data-using-json